# Using macro variable in an IF statement within a loop is not working

Tags: sas

I am having an issue with my code where it is working when I am hard coding the value (in comments) in the IF statement but when I insert the macro variable, the functions 'Copy' and 'Delete' do not work with no errors generated. Below is the code being used:

```
*%let pathscr = //files/FEB_P000/Reporting_FS;

%let pathdes = //files/FEB_P000/Reporting_FS/Accounting log/2021;

%let fn = LFNPAccounting;

%let dt = %sysfunc(inputn(&acc_date, yymmddn8.),yymmddn8.); /* 20211209 */

%let Var = &fn&dt;/* LFNPAccounting20211209 */

data _null_;

  length fref $8 fname $256;

  did = filename(fref,'\\files\FEB_P000\Reporting_FS');

  did = dopen(fref);

  do i = 1 to dnum(did);

    fname = dread(did,i);

    newfn = SUBSTR(fname,1,22);

    if newfn = &Var then do;

    /*if newfn = 'LFNPAccounting20211209' then do;*/  

      rc1=filename('src',catx('/',"&pathscr",fname));

      rc2=filename('des',catx('/',"&pathdes",fname));

      rc3=fcopy('src','des');

      rc4= fdelete('src');

    end;

  end;

run;*
```

Could anyone help please?

Thanks
Hans

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you try to look into a specified folder `pathscr`, and if a file matches a certain string (`SUBSTR(fname,1,22)`), you copy and delete the latter to the Logs folder `pathdes`.

```
libname report "/home/kermit/temp/Reporting/";

data report.have20211210
     report.have20211209
     report.have20211208;
    id = 1;
    output;
run;

%let pathscr = /home/kermit/temp/Reporting/;
%let pathdes = /home/kermit/temp/Logs/;
%let fn = have; /* Name of the file */
%let type = .sas7bdat; /* File extension */
%let dt = %sysfunc(inputn(%sysfunc(today()), yymmddn8.), yymmddn8.);

%let file = &fn&dt&type.;
%put &=file;

data _null_;
   drop rc did;
   rc=filename("mydir", "&pathscr.");
   did=dopen("mydir");
   if did > 0 then do; /* check that the directory can be opened */
        do i=1 to dnum(did); /* use dnum() to determine the highest possible member number */
            fname=dread(did, i); /* get the name of the file */
            if fname = "&file." then do; /* if the name of the file match: */
                rc=filename('src', "&pathscr&file.");
                rc=filename('des', "&pathdes&file.");
                rc=fcopy('src', 'des'); /* copy from source to destination */
                rc=fdelete('src'); /* delete from source */
            end;
        end;
   end;
   else do; /* if directory cannot be open, put the error message to the logs */
      msg=sysmsg();
      put msg;
   end;
run;

Logs:
FILE=have20211210.sas7bdat
```

[DOPEN](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/vdmmlcdc/1.0/lefunctionsref/n0hpa8p9kacbran1ndqiw3krwohq.htm) opens a directory and returns a directory identifier value (a number greater than 0) that is used to identify the open directory in other SAS external file access functions. If the directory cannot be opened, DOPEN returns 0, and you can obtain the error message by calling the SYSMSG function.

I used `today()` for the `dt` macro-variable for convenience sake, but you will have to change it to whatever date you are searching for.

Consider that with the code above, if the file is already in the Logs folder, it will **not** be overwritten. Note that you do not have to use the CATX function if you put another `/` at the very end of your specified path.

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Macro variables are not resolved when bounded by single quotes.  They are resolved when within double quotes.

Try

```
did = filename(fref,"&path_scr");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Richard!

Answer (score 0):

You set VAR to a value like:

```
%let Var = LFNPAccounting20211209 ;
```

Then you use it to generate a SAS statement:

```
if newfn = &Var then do;
```

Which will resolve to

```
if newfn = LFNPAccounting20211209 then do;
```

Since I did not see you creating any variable named LFNPAccounting20211209 it is most likely that you want to use this statement instead:

```
if newfn = "&Var" then do;
```

So that the SAS code you generate will compare the value of NEWFN to a string literal instead of another variable.

Note: Since it looks like you are using WINDOWS filesystem you should make the comparison case insenstive.

```
if upcase(newfn) = %upcase("&Var") then do;
```

Comment: That's awesome Tom!
It worked :)